# Angular 6 run *ngIf once or disable ng functionalities on an element

Tags: angular

Is it possible to disable *ngIf after it is called upon an element ? 
Or perhaps to disable this element ng functionalities and keep it static ?

Use case :

On a search result page, every result has some nav-tabs (bootstrap)  and inside them there are carousels, which I want to be called when the user has clicked on the nav menu. But the function I have activates the carousel which is clicked so I want to disable the *ngIf or make it static.

Comment: Can you give more information about the use case?

Comment: CAn you please explain in detail with an example

Comment: You can always keep the `ngIf` condition true once it's true in your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change the value of the variable, the *ngIf will be static. 
In any case, if what you want is to work directly with the HTML DOM, I leave this tutorial that will help you to completely disable an HTML element when you indicate it:

https://dzone.com/articles/conditionally-enabling-and-disabling-dom-elements

If you need more help, give me a comment with the questions and I'll help you solve them